# How to do type inference with enums in Scala?

Tags: scala, types, enums

I have different kinds of enumerations in this flavour

```
class Gender extends Enumeration {
    type Gender = Value
    val Male,Female = Value
}
```

and I would like to have a generic function that given an element of an enumeration, it puts a 1 in an array of length .maxId (if you are familiar with R, I'm trying to implement **factor**). But I'm not able to get the types right, my function would be something like this (wrong) code:

```
def toFactor[T](elem:T.Value):List[Double] = {
  var array = Array.fill(T.maxId)(0.0)
  array(elem.id) == 1.0
  array.toList
}
```

How would you write this code so is generic for whatever enumeration we use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should do it:

```
object Gender extends Enumeration {
    type Gender = Value
    val Male, Female = Value
}

def toFactor[E <: Enumeration, V <: E#Value](enum: E, elem: V): List[Double] = {
  var array = Array.fill(enum.maxId)(0.0)
  array(elem.id) = 1.0
  array.toList
}

println(toFactor(Gender, Gender.Female)) // prints: List(0.0, 1.0)
```

You need to use `E#Value` instead of `E.Value` because it generally tells: any `Value` of the provided `Enumeration` `E`. `E <: Enumeration` restricts `E` to be subclass of `Enumeration`. You also need enum instance in order to get `maxId`.

#### Update

You can also simplify `toFactor` method a little bit and avoid using any `Array`s or `id`s:

```
def toFactor[T <: Enumeration, V <: T#Value](enum: T, elem: V): List[Double] = 
      enum.values.toList map (curr => if (curr == elem) 1.0 else 0.0)
```